# How do I get the URL for a dropped image using a Chrome userscript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop, dom-events

In the following chrome user script, how can I get a url for an image that I drag from my desktop?
Where I have the `debugger` line, I'm getting the empty string for `e.dataTransfer.getData("text")` and `e.dataTransfer.getData("url")`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match http://*/*
// @match https://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

function preventDrag(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  console.log("Just dropped: " + e.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
  debugger
  // TODO: grab the url for e.dataTransfer.files[0]

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
document.addEventListener('dragenter', preventDrag, false);
document.addEventListener('dragover', preventDrag, false);
```

Comment: So the call to console log does correctly log the filename?

Comment: @Fresh yes, it reports the filename, but without any path.

Comment: Not sure to understand well, but if I do, you won't be able to have a file path (meaning the dropped file fullpath). It's a "protection" from browsers.

But you can at least get the name of it.
Here is a jsFiddle of how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/U8yqL/1/

Comment: @Leiko Thanks for the fiddle! I was able to use readAsDataURL to get the file contents themselves, which isn't as elegant as a `file:// url` but I'll settle for that. Would you mind writing it up as an answer so I can award the bounty?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not sure I understand it well, but if I do, you won't be able to have a file path (meaning the dropped file fullpath).
It's a "protection" from browsers. But you can at least get the name of it.

```
var file   = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0],
    reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function (event) {
    console.log(file);
    // filename is in file.name
    // ... do something here
}

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Here is a jsFiddle of how to do it: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8yqL/1)

Comment: why does the code work on jsfiddle and not on my computer? I tried the code from jsfiddle on my computer but images dropped onto the box just open in full screen with no image name

Comment: But the onDrop even does have access to the path: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrop.asp

Answer (score 1):

A file (when you use `console.log(file)` to log dropped file) in chrome is like:

```
{
  name: "a.txt", // file name
  size: 2473, // 2kb
  type: "text/plain", // file type
  lastModified: 1613374662130, // lastModifed
  lastModifiedDate: ..., // lastModifed Date
  arrayBuffer: ... // Buffer for reading the content
}
```

But you don't have access to the `path` or `fullPath` of it (for security reasons).

Also you can read its content by [FileReaderApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).